# Golang packet strcuture returning buffer

Tags: function, struct, go, byte, packet

I have made a packet package with a packet structure inside like so:

```
//A packet buffer object
package Packet

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
)

type Packet struct {
    buffer bytes.Buffer
}

func (p Packet) GetBytes() []byte {
    return p.buffer.Bytes()
}

func (p Packet) AddString(s string) {
    p.buffer.Write([]byte(s))
}

func (p Packet) AddInt(i_ int) {
    //Convert int to byte
    b := make([]byte, 2)
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(b, uint16(i_))
    //Push byte to buffer
    p.buffer.Write([]byte(b))
}

func (p Packet) AddByte(b []byte) {
    p.buffer.Write(b)
}
```

This is the session package that uses the packet structure to form packets and send them to the client

```
package Session

type MapleSession struct {
    connection net.Conn
    EncryptIV, DecryptIV []byte
    isConnected bool
}

func (session *MapleSession) Run(conn net.Conn) { 
    //Display where the new connection is coming from
    session.connection = conn
    fmt.Println("Client connected from:", session.connection.RemoteAddr())

    //Set the user connected variable on
    session.isConnected = true

    //Send Handshake
    packet := MaplePacket.CreateHandShake(&session.EncryptIV, &session.DecryptIV, 40, "", []byte("0x05"))
    session.connection.Write(packet)
}
```

This is the MaplePacket package that creates the packets to send to the client that are requested from the session package

```
package MaplePacket

func CreateHandShake (eIV, dIV *[]byte, version int, location string, locale []byte) []byte{
    packet := Packet.Packet{}

    //Create IVs
    *eIV = (make([]byte, 4))
    n1, _ := rand.Read(*eIV)
    *dIV = (make([]byte, 4))
    n2, _ := rand.Read(*dIV)

    if (n1 + n2 < 8) {
        fmt.Println("Error in IV generation")
    }    

    //Create the packet
    packet.AddInt(version)
    packet.AddString(location)
    packet.AddByte(*dIV)
    packet.AddByte(*eIV)
    packet.AddByte(locale)

    fmt.Println(packet.GetBytes())

    return packet.GetBytes()
}
```

However when creating a packet like in the example above and adding values, the Packet.GetBytes() returns an empty array. Is bytes.Buffer the correct way to go about this is? Or am I going completely wrong in how I am approaching this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go passes all arguments, including receivers, by value.

Try using pointer receivers: `(p *Packet)`. `bytes.Buffer` contains state information which is being discarded.

---

> [package bytes](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/)
>
> ```
> // Simple byte buffer for marshaling data.
> // A Buffer is a variable-sized buffer of bytes with Read and Write methods.
> // The zero value for Buffer is an empty buffer ready to use.
> type Buffer struct {
>   buf       []byte            // contents are the bytes buf[off : len(buf)]
>   off       int               // read at &buf[off], write at &buf[len(buf)]
>   runeBytes [utf8.UTFMax]byte // avoid allocation of slice on each WriteByte or Rune
>   bootstrap [64]byte          // memory to hold first slice; helps small buffers (Printf) avoid allocation.
>   lastRead  readOp            // last read operation, so that Unread* can work correctly.
> }
> ```

---

> The Go Programming Language
>
> [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html)
>
> Methods
>
> [Pointers vs. Values](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values)
>
> The rule about pointers vs. values for receivers is that value methods
>   can be invoked on pointers and values, but pointer methods can only be
>   invoked on pointers. This is because pointer methods can modify the
>   receiver; invoking them on a copy of the value would cause those
>   modifications to be discarded.

Your type `Package` type is equivalent to the following.

```
type Packet struct {
    buffer /* bytes.Buffer */ struct {
    buf       []byte            // contents are the bytes buf[off : len(buf)]
    off       int               // read at &buf[off], write at &buf[len(buf)]
    runeBytes [utf8.UTFMax]byte // avoid allocation of slice on each WriteByte or Rune
    bootstrap [64]byte          // memory to hold first slice; helps small buffers (Printf) avoid allocation.
    lastRead  readOp            // last read operation, so that Unread* can work correctly.
}
```

You pass a copy (by value) of a `Package` type variable to the methods. The copy is updated to reflect the new state and, upon return is discarded.

Comment: I finaly realised what you meant! Thanks for the help.